# How to add pagination to this custom wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

```
<main id="main" class="site-main">
        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

        <?php
        $args = array(
          'posts_per_page' => 4,
          'paged' => $paged,
            'order'=> 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date'
        );
        $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>

        <?php
           while($custom_query->have_posts()) :
              $custom_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="bloggy-post">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ?></a>
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>">Read More...</a>
            <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
        </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>

    </main>
```

Ive tried to add functions to my functions.php file and wordpress navigation functions. nothings worked

this code is inside a page template called blog linked to a static page that creates the loop

I have 5 posts and i want a new page to be added every fifth posts

edit: i forgot to put the site: https://goodsleep.desertsunstudio.com

its a portofolio piece for main site

[El Paso Web Design and Graphic Design | Desert Sun Studio](https://www.desertsunstudio.com)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue the pagination wasnt being called correctly

```
<main id="main" class="site-main">
        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

        <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

        $args = array(
          'posts_per_page' => 4,
          'paged' => $paged,
            'order'=> 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date'
        );
        $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>

        <?php
           while($custom_query->have_posts()) :
              $custom_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="bloggy-post">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ?></a>
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>">Read More...</a>
            <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
        </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
         <?php
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

            echo paginate_links( array(
                 'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                 'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                 'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                 'total' =>  $custom_query->max_num_pages
            ) );
         ?>

    </main>
```